# How call an object property from a click event inside a method of the same object

Tags: javascript

In a object, how can i make a call to the propertyA from methodA someElement click without rewrite the name of the container object. Thanks. (i'm sorry for my poor english).

```
var testObject = testObject || {
  propertyA: true,

  methodA: function(){
    $('someElement').on('click', function(event){
        testObject.propertyA = false; //here, how can i call propertyA without rewrite testObject, i want something generic    
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could define a variable that would store the current reference, like `self`.

```
var testObject = testObject || {

    propertyA: true,

    methodA: function(){
        var self = this;
        $('someElement').on('click', function(event){
            self.propertyA = false;     
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @zerkms you are correct. I just corrected it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: And now hope that the method is called as `testObject.methodA()` and not assigned as a reference and called from there, like `window.onload = testObject.methodA;`.

Comment: @PantaAlejandro you are welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to set an object reference to the object while calling `methodA` and use it in the handler to refer to the object.

```
var testObject = testObject || {
    propertyA: true,
    methodA: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('someElement').on('click', function (event) {
            self.propertyA = false;
        });
    }
}
```